# how to style parents cousin element while achieving a child element condition

Tags: html, css

```
div>input:not([disabled]) ~ label{
  color:green;
}
```

> the above piece of code will target "child cousin" but I want to target the "parent cousin" element . >how can I achieve this using CSS.

```
<div>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text" disabled>
  <label>child cousin</label>
</div>
<label>parent cousin</label>
```

Comment: I think you must consider rewriting your question properly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: it cannot be done with css - there is no parent selector

Answer (score -1):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/8155150), the is still no parent selector using css, I suggest you use javascript for that.